# How do I let VSCode's CMake extension find my C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, installation, cmake

I'm using the CMake extension in VSCode and am trying to compile a C++ code (on an Ubuntu virtual machine). The compilation used to work, but suddenly stopped working and I don't know the cause.

In the CMake extension from VSCode the CMake files no longer appear and I am receiving the following error when trying to use the configure all projects button of the extension:

```
[main] Configuring project: zweites-projekt 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang++ -S/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt -B/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - broken
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[cmake] See also "/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[cmake] CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
[cmake]   The C++ compiler
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "/usr/bin/clang++"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: /home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_0d052/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/build
[cmake]     gmake[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp“ wird betreten
[cmake]     Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
[cmake]     /usr/bin/clang++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
[cmake]     Linking CXX executable cmTC_0d052
[cmake]     /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
[cmake]     /usr/bin/clang++ CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_0d052 
[cmake]     /usr/bin/ld: -lstdc++ kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
[cmake]     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[cmake]     gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_0d052.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_0d052] Fehler 1
[cmake]     gmake[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp“ wird verlassen
[cmake]     gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_0d052/fast] Fehler 2
[cmake]     
[cmake]     
[cmake] 
[cmake]   
[cmake] 
[cmake]   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang++ -S/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt -B/home/odin/Schreibtisch/zweites-projekt/build -G "Unix Makefiles" exited with code: 1
```

I already checked that clang is installed (using clang --version in the VSCode terminal) in the terminal and selected the this compiler path "/usr/bin/clang++-14" under "C/C++ Edit Configurations".

How do I fix this?

Comment: english diagnostic messages would be nice :|

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: -lstdc++ kann nicht gefunden werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
> ```

Install `libstdc++-12-dev`

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```

You may need to pick another available version of 9, 10, 11, 12.